# Reading, adding and editing excel in c# with graph and data and

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I have one odd requirement using Microsoft excel and c#, I have one excel generated automatically as an output from firmware.. the excel doesn't contains predefined number of columns nor it contains predefined number of sheets..

The output in the excel contains values which are results of tests with the firmware, also the excel contains graphs (line chart) which are generated using the values of tests..

I need such and mechanism, wherein i could encrypt the excel so as to prevent any manipulation of data in excel.. also if one needs to edit the data inside the excel he/she needs an password to edit it and also edit log gets maintained i.e. what was the previous data and what is edited and in which sheet and which cell.

I have done the encryption part i.e. encrypting the excel.. also i have made the function of decrypting the excel and reading it..

but the data is in odd manner i.e. it has wrap-text, graph etc... I want to read excel as it is in c# and also maintain edit log for the thing..

i have googled a lot, and also tried using VSTO but didn't met the requirement..

Please help me .. i m really stuck..

Krunal

Comment: Have you tried using Open Xml SDK to manipulate Excel spreadsheets ?

Comment: Also what do you exactly need,, Read Excel or Write excel sheets

Comment: For Excel 2010 and above, Microsoft has `Interop` assemblies. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597926(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I want to read excel and also manipulate (edit) that excel and also need to maintain logs for the edited cell..

Comment: Also i want to read the excel as it is as google spreadsheet does...i need it in c# (win forms)

Comment: What is your Spreadsheet extension.. is it .XLSX or XLS ?

Comment: it is office 2003 - .xls

Comment: Sorry I provided a answer assuming you used 2007 .XLSX format.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is provided assuming you have spredsheet with .XLSX file format  and NOT XLS

I think you can use Open XML SDK for this task.

Open XMl SDK allows you to manipulate Open XML file formats which include default spreadsheet format .XLSX

I cannot say how exactly you can CODE all your requirements. But using Open XML you can read spreadsheets and extract their data to your C# program [Read file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571(v=office.15).aspx] . Also you have open xml productivity tool which allows you to explore a spreadsheet as C# CODEs [ Reffer - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA Download- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425] This will help to understand how charts [your documents have them as you mentioned] are structured in spreadsheet so you can read them correctly to C# application.

Also go through these examples by MSDN -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850837(v=office.15).aspx

Also learn about SDK and its features - http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/bb456487(v=office.15).aspx

Structure of a Spreadsheet - http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278316(v=office.15).aspx

Once you have done your edits you may change your Excel sheet using same SDK.

-Happy Coding-